# Hello, how can I have the 2 stripes of my label not deformed at the edge? Thank you

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: stripe deformed bcz of the sub surf]
this is due to the sub surf modifier I presume but I want to keep it. I thought of limiting the uv map to the second edge on the left instead of the outmost left one but I don't know how, or even if that's the correct way to fix it. Thank youin advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, try *Advanced > UV Smooth > Keep Corners* or another one than the current:

[image]

Comment: Merci beaucoup @moonboots. I really like your tutorials keep up the good work !

Comment: Hey thanks!  ;))